# How can I reload data on my UICollectionView?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, uicollectionview

I need to reload my images every time the UICollectionView is called. I currently have two buttons (and more to come) that segue to and populate the UICollectionView via a Parse.com query. When I click on my button, the images are downloaded, and there is a segue to the UICollectionView, but the images only display when I tap "Back" and re-enter the UICollectionView. I've tried using self.collectionView.reloadData() but I only get an error.

```
var images = [UIImage]()
var imageFiles = [PFFile]()
class CollectionCollectionViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

@IBAction func xy1Button(sender: AnyObject) {



}

@IBAction func xy2Button(sender: AnyObject) {
    var downloadImages = PFQuery(className: "XY2")
    downloadImages.whereKey("Expansion", equalTo: "XY2")
    downloadImages.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            println("Successfully retrieved \(objects!.count) images.")
            if let objects = objects as? [PFObject] {
                for object in objects {
                    imageFiles.append(object["Image"] as! PFFile)
                }
            }
        } else {
            println("Error: \(error!) \(error!.userInfo!)")
        }
    }

    self.collectionView.reloadData()
//ERROR IS ABOVE: "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION(code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)"

    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("jumpToCollectionView", sender: self)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {



}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return imageFiles.count

}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell: CardsCollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CardsCollectionViewCell
    imageFiles[indexPath.row].getDataInBackgroundWithBlock{
        (imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        if error == nil {

            let image = UIImage(data: imageData!)

            cell.Img.image = image
        }
    }
    return cell
}
}
```

Any help?!

Comment: Is collectionView a valid object the first time its loaded (are you sure its not null)?

Comment: That's the problem. It is null the first time it is loaded.

Comment: Right so you need to initialize it, whats the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try to include `self.collectionView.reloadData()` in the  asynchronous dispatches like this :

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        self.collectionView.reloadData()
    })
```

I hope I have helped you!

Answer (score -1):

Try calling self.collectionview.collectionviewlayout.invalidatelayout() to force update the layout of the CollectionView and thus refreshing your UI. Otherwise, please provide more information as your question is not that clear.

Comment: This is at best a comment.

Comment: @Aggressor no need for the minus one .. it was an answer just like the guy above me which you haven't given a minus ... so chill out buddy !